# Ruby On Rails Blog Creation Tutorial

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-4

The tutorial is stating in section 5:8 the following:

'5.8 Listing all posts
We still need a way to list all our posts, so let's do that. We'll use a specific route from `config/routes.rb`:'

and providing code such as:

```
'posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index'
```

But it does not mention where to place this code, or what to do with it- it states what to do with the following two areas, and how the code should look, but does not here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give me a link to the Section of the Tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

The line you provide is not code, it is the output of `rake routes`, which shows you the routes configured in your application. You have two ways to create the requested route:

Recommended: if "posts" is a RESTful resource, you can declare it as a resource, by adding this line to `config/routes.rb'

```
resources :photos
```

This will add several routes to your app; `rake routes` should output something like this:

```
              posts GET     /posts(.:format)                   posts#index
              posts POST    /posts(.:format)                   posts#create
           new_post GET     /posts/new(.:format)               posts#new
          edit_post GET     /posts/:id/edit(.:format)          posts#edit
               post GET     /posts/:id(.:format)               posts#show
                    PATCH   /posts/:id(.:format)               posts#update
                    PUT     /posts/:id(.:format)               posts#update
                    DELETE  /posts/:id(.:format)               posts#destroy
```

If you just want to add the index action, you can instead add the following line to `config/routes.rb`:

```
get 'posts', to: 'posts#index'
```

If the tutorial asked you to create the resource with `rails generate scaffold`, the relevant line to routes.rb would have been added automatically by the generator.